# Solrj getBeans() unable to fit response into bean

Tags: java, solrj

For the field type text_general getbeans() method returning that field value as ArrayList() but field in pojo is String(While indexing same pojo was used).Also I have multiValued attribute to false.

managed-schema:

`<field name="description" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>`

pojo-field :

```
@Field("description")
private String description;
//getter-setter method
```

Java-code:

```
SolrClient client = new HttpSolrClient.Builder("http://localhost:8983/solr/audiovideo").build();
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter Serach : ");
    String search = sc.nextLine();
    SolrQuery query = new SolrQuery();
    query.setQuery("description:" + search);
    query.setStart(0);    
    QueryResponse response = client.query(query);             
    List<AudioVideoPojo> results = response.getBeans(AudioVideoPojo.class);
```

Exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.solr.client.solrj.beans.BindingException: Could not instantiate object of class com.mycompany.solrdemo1.AudioVideoPojo
at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.beans.DocumentObjectBinder.getBean(DocumentObjectBinder.java:71)
at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.beans.DocumentObjectBinder.getBeans(DocumentObjectBinder.java:50)
at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.response.QueryResponse.getBeans(QueryResponse.java:618)
at com.mycompany.solrdemo1.Main.getDataSolrFromDatabase(Main.java:155)
at com.mycompany.solrdemo1.Main.main(Main.java:131)
Caused by: org.apache.solr.client.solrj.beans.BindingException: Exception while setting value : [India International Music Festival] on private java.lang.String com.mycompany.solrdemo1.AudioVideoPojo.description
at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.beans.DocumentObjectBinder$DocField.set(DocumentObjectBinder.java:455)
at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.beans.DocumentObjectBinder$DocField.inject(DocumentObjectBinder.java:438)
at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.beans.DocumentObjectBinder.getBean(DocumentObjectBinder.java:67)

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set java.lang.String field com.mycompany.solrdemo1.AudioVideoPojo.description to java.util.ArrayList
at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:167)
at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:171)
at sun.reflect.UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.set(UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.java:81)
at java.lang.reflect.Field.set(Field.java:764)
at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.beans.DocumentObjectBinder$DocField.set(DocumentObjectBinder.java:449)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set `multiValued` attribute to `false`.  As per reference guide, it defaults to `false` for `fieldTypes`. But it is not honouring the default.